# Подскажите алгоритм решения задачи. Рассадка пассажиров

Tags: алгоритм

Условие:

В самолете n рядов и по три кресла слева и справа в каждом ряду. Крайние кресла (A и F) находятся у окна, центральные (C и D) – у прохода. На регистрацию приходят группы из одного, двух или трех пассажиров. Они желают сидеть рядом, то есть на одном ряду и на одной стороне: левой или правой. Например, группа из двух пассажиров может сесть на кресла B и C, но не может сесть на кресла C и D, потому что они разделены проходом, а также не может сесть на кресла A и C, потому что тогда они окажутся не рядом. Кроме того, один из пассажиров каждой группы очень требовательный – он хочет сесть либо у окна, либо у прохода. Конечно же, каждая группа из пассажиров хочет занять места в ряду с как можно меньшим номером, ведь тогда они скорее выйдут из самолета после посадки. Для каждой группы пассажиров определите, есть ли места в самолете, подходящие для них.

Формат ввода
Первая строка содержит число n ( 1 ≤ n ≤ 100 ) – количество рядов в самолете. Далее в n строках вводится изначальная рассадка в самолете по рядам (от первого до n-го), где символами . (точка) обозначены свободные места, символами # (решетка) обозначены занятые места, а символами _ (нижнее подчеркивание) обозначен проход между креслами C и D каждого ряда.

Следующая строка содержит число m ( 1 ≤ m ≤ 100 ) – количество групп пассажиров. Далее в m строках содержатся описания групп пассажиров. Формат описания такой: num side position , где num – количество пассажиров (число 1, 2 или 3), side – желаемая сторона самолета (строка left или right), position – желаемое место требовательного пассажира (строка aisle или window).

Формат вывода
Если группа может сесть на места, удовлетворяющие ее требованиям, то выведите строку Passengers can take seats: и список их мест в формате row letter, упорядоченный по возрастанию буквы места. Затем выведите в n строках получившуюся рассадку в самолете, в формате, описанном выше, причем места, занятые текущей группой пассажиров, должны быть обозначены символом X. Если группа не может найти места, удовлетворяющие ее требованиям, то выведите строку Cannot fulfill passengers requirements. Ответ сравнивается с правильным посимвольно, поэтому ваше решение не должно выводить никаких лишних символов, в том числе лишних переводов строк или пробельных символов в концах строк. В конце каждой строки (включая последнюю) должен быть выведен символ перевода строки.

**ПРИМЕР ВВОДА:**

```
4
..._.#.
.##_...
.#._.##
..._...
7
2 left aisle
3 right window
2 left window
3 left aisle
1 right window
2 right window
1 right window
```

**ПРИМЕР ВЫВОДА:**

```
Passengers can take seats: 1B 1C
.XX_.#.
.##_...
.#._.##
..._...
Passengers can take seats: 2D 2E 2F
.##_.#.
.##_XXX
.#._.##
..._...
Passengers can take seats: 4A 4B
.##_.#.
.##_###
.#._.##
XX._...
Cannot fulfill passengers requirements
Passengers can take seats: 1F
.##_.#X
.##_###
.#._.##
##._...
Passengers can take seats: 4E 4F
.##_.##
.##_###
.#._.##
##._.XX
Cannot fulfill passengers requirements
```

Можете подсказать пожалуйста, примерную логику, куда думать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да вроде просто брать, да сравнивать.

Можно битовые маски ввести для компактности сравнений.

Пример битовых масок для сидений: `{0b000010, 0b011000,0b010011,0b000000}`

Для групп: `{0b011000, 0b000111...}`

Если битовая маска группы при `and` с очередным рядом даёт не ноль, то не сесть, надо смотреть следующий ряд.

Когда нашли ряд - обновляем маску сидений этого ряда с помощью `or` с маской группы

Comment: Вы описали жадный алгоритм. Этого достаточно?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Думаю, требование `занять места в ряду с как можно меньшим номером,`, т.е. первый же подходящий -  подразумевает жадность, а об оптимизации в условии речи вообще не ведётся

Comment: Согласен. Пропустил, когда читал задачу.