# Вывести забронированные места в самолете (Python)

Tags: python, алгоритм

Возникли сложности с решением задачи, определяющей наличие посадочных мест в самолете и выводящей схему салона с забронированными и занятыми местами. Формат ввода и вывода, подробные условия ниже:
[image: условие]
[image: ввод]
[image: вывод]
[image: Пример]

На данный момент имеется код, выводящий первоначальный план самолета, а также преобразовывающий текстовый ввод в те индексы каждой строки (ряда) первоначального плана салона самолета, которые надо заменить на Х, а затем на #. Дальше не очень понятно, каким образом написать цикл, который правильно бы бронировал места.

```
n = int(input())
seats = [[i for i in input()] for _ in range(n)]

m = int(input())
passengers = [input().split() for _ in range(m)]
passengers2 = [[] for _ in range(m)]
# place2 = 'ABCDEF'
for i in range(m):
    if passengers[i][1] == 'left':
        if passengers[i][2] == 'aisle':
            # passengers2[i].append(place2[-3-int(passengers[i][0]):3])
            passengers2[i] = list(range(3 - int(passengers[i][0]), 3))
        else:
            # passengers2[i].append(place2[:4-int(passengers[i][0])])
            passengers2[i] = list(range(0, int(passengers[i][0])))
    if passengers[i][1] == 'right':
        if passengers[i][2] == 'aisle':
            # passengers2[i].append(place2[4:4+int(passengers[i][0])])
            passengers2[i] = list(range(4, 4 + int(passengers[i][0])))
        else:
            # passengers2[i].append(place2[6-int(passengers[i][0]):6])
            passengers2[i] = list(range(7 - int(passengers[i][0]), 7))
    # passengers2[i] = ''.join(passengers2[i])

print(passengers2)
# print(list(range(2, -2 + int(passengers[0][0]), -1)))
for i in range(n):
    print(''.join(seats[i]))
print()

print(seats)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подскажите алгоритм решения задачи. Рассадка пассажиров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1474920/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%a0%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2)